# I can't deploy the project in Heroku with vs code

Tags: heroku, deployment

I was trying to deploy my project to heroku but couldn't do it cause I got application error. I checked the logs and what i got. I already two times created a new project and deploying its to heroku but it had no effect My logs: Maybe somebody could help me!

````
    npm ERR! While resolving: @testing-library/react@13.4.0
    npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
    npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3" from @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.2.0
    npm ERR!   node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome
    npm ERR!     @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@"^0.2.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!   3 more (react-dom, react-scripts, react-toastify)
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
    npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
    npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
    npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! For a full report see:
    npm ERR! /tmp/npmcache.QP9dc/_logs/2023-05-09T22_13_21_507Z-eresolve-report.txt
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.QP9dc/_logs/2023-05-09T22_13_21_507Z-debug-0.log
    -----> Build failed```
````